# How pass username/password command line options to jndi grails.naming.entries in Config.grooy

Tags: grails, passwords, jndi

I have a jndi entry in Config.groovy like so:

```
grails.naming.entries = ['jdbc/test_me': [
    type: "javax.sql.DataSource", //required
        auth: "Container", // optional
        description: "Data source for ...", //optional
        //properties for particular type of resource
    url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@testserver:1521:SID",
    username: "someuser",
    password: "somepassword",
    driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
    maxActive: "8", //and so on
        maxIdle: "4"
    ]
]
```

This works fine but I do not want to store the username/password in the Config.groovy source.  Is there a way to pass the credential from command line options, -Duser=someuser -Dpass-somepassword, to grails.naming.entries in Config.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use externally stored configuration settings.

This allows Grails to load in unique settings for the production (or test or dev) server, that are not stored within the grails application WAR.  The other nice thing is that these can be updated without replacing any code, just restart the application on the server.

Example from [this great article on the subject](http://blog.zmok.net/articles/2009/04/22/playing-with-grails-application-configuration):

```
// Put this at the top of your Config.groovy
// Copied from http://blog.zmok.net/articles/2009/04/22/playing-with-grails-application-configuration
if(System.getenv("MY_GREAT_CONFIG")) {
    println( "Including configuration file: " + System.getenv("MY_GREAT_CONFIG"));
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.getenv("MY_GREAT_CONFIG")
} else {
    println "No external configuration file defined."
}
```

Now set the environment variable `MY_GREAT_CONFIG` to the absolute path for the external groovy config.  See the link for a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

It appears any options added via grails.config.locations are not available in Config.groovy.  "${System.getProperty('password')}".toString() is the only way this worked.
Here are my test results:

Added at the beginning of Config.groovy:

```
if (new File("${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy").exists()){
    grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]
}
```

Added at the end of Config.groovy:

```
println "(*) grails.config.locations = ${grails.config.locations}"
def f = new File("${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy")
f.eachLine{ line -> println line }
println "test password: ${testPassword}" // same result ([:]) with grails.config.testPassword
println "${System.getProperty('password')}"

grails.naming.entries = ['jdbc/test_mnr': [
    type: "javax.sql.DataSource", //required
    auth: "Container", // optional
    description: "Data source for ...",
    url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:SID",
    username: "username",
    password: "${System.getProperty('password')}".toString(),
    driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
    maxActive: "8",
    maxIdle: "4",
    removeAbandoned: "true",
    removeAbandonedTimeout: "60",
    testOnBorrow: "true",
    logAbandoned: "true",
    factory: "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory",
    validationQuery: "select count(*) from dual",
    maxWait: "-1"
  ]
]
```

Content of user.home/.grails/mnroad-config.groovy:

```
testPassword='some_password'
```

Here is the result when run with -Dpassword=somePassword :

```
(*) grails.config.locations = [file:C:\Documents and Settings\carr1den/.grails/mnroad-config.groovy]
testPassword=some_password
test password: [:]
somePassword
```

The grailsApplication.config.testPassword option is available after the app initializes.